# Is it possible to substitute Vue.extend with new Vue?

Tags: vuejs2, quasar-framework

I am working on a Quasar project and I am having a problem. I need to access from external javascript to the properties and methods of the Vue component.

```js
const vue = Vue.extend({
  name: 'PageIndex',
  data() {
    return {
      accessToken:
        'myToken',
      mapStyle: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
      coordinates: { lng: -82.42642875898966, lat: 23.11975881338755 },
      barbershopsSource: {
        type: 'FeatureCollection',
        features: [
          {
            type: 'Feature',
            properties: {
              title: 'Foo'
            },
            geometry: {
              type: 'Point',
              coordinates: [-82.42644475189455, 23.119620627441506]
            }
          },
          {
            type: 'Feature',
            properties: {
              title: 'Bar'
            },
            geometry: {
              type: 'Point',
              coordinates: [-82.42193696725194, 23.124402891576594]
            }
          },
          {
            type: 'Feature',
            properties: {
              title: 'Baz'
            },
            geometry: {
              type: 'Point',
              coordinates: [-82.43414198682088, 23.115900071933567]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    };
  },
  components: {},
  methods: {
    createMap() {
      mapboxgl.accessToken = this.accessToken;
      const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: this.mapStyle, // stylesheet location
        center: this.coordinates, // starting position [lng, lat]
        zoom: 15 // starting zoom
      });
      const source = this.barbershopsSource;
      map.on('load', function() {
        console.log('Map loaded');
        //I want to have access to the component properties here
      });
      map.on('click', 'barbershops', function(e) {
        console.log('Barbershop clicked:', e.lngLat);
      });
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.createMap();
  }
});

export default vue;
```

I know that access to properties is pretty simple, but the thing is that by default and I don't know why, Quasar uses Vue.extend to create the components. If I substitute

```js
const vue = Vue.extend
```

by

```js
const vue = new Vue
```

I can access to properties, but the component view isn't loaded.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The way it works is, quasar takes `App.vue` as the entry point and loads the generated compiled javascript. The app is created there.

There is only one app running.
You add functionality to your vue app by extend the app.

You create app once in `App.vue` and add functionality to it by extending.

Comment: Thanks, could you give me some links were I can found more information about this?